# A Lot of 90% Proportions

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

In the land of Puzzovania Sock Enrage:

- More than 90% of the puzzles are tagged with both [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle) and [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics).
- More than 90% of the puzzles are tagged with both [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle) and [logical-deduction](/questions/tagged/logical-deduction).

Show that among the puzzles tagged with both [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) and [logical-deduction](/questions/tagged/logical-deduction), more than 90% are also tagged [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle).

---

<sub>Notes:</sub>

1. This is harder than it looks!
2. Based on a puzzle from the Russian Tournament of the Towns.

Comment: It's easy; Puzzovania Sock Enrage requires that all questions be tagged [tag:riddle] therefore 100% of the questions that are tagged [tag:mathematics] and [tag:logical-deduction]  are also tagged [tag:riddle] . 100%>90%..... Oh, wait. This is tagged [tag:logical-deduction], not [tag:lateral-thinking].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $A_{RM}$ be puzzles tagged riddle and math, but not logical-deduction, and define $A_{LM}$, $A_{RL}$ and $A_{RLM}$ similarly.

From 1: $A_{RM} + A_{RLM} > 9(A_{RL} + A_{LM})$ (a)
From 2: $A_{RL} + A_{RLM} > 9(A_{RM} + A_{LM})$ (b)

Adding (a) and (b):

$$2A_{RLM} > 8A_{RL} + 8A_{RM} + 18A_{LM}$$
$$A_{RLM} > 4A_{RL} + 4A_{RM} + 9A_{LM}$$

Since all $A$s are non-negative, this implies $A_{RLM} > 9A_{LM}$, as desired.

Comment: You make it look easy :-) Note that inequalities (a) and (b) aren't the most natural things to conclude from the given conditions: in fact $A_{RM}+A_{RLM}>9($all the rest$)$, and you have to see which terms to chuck out and which to keep. Did a Venn diagram help at all, or did you just do this with algebra?

Comment: A bit of both - I drew a Venn diagram to help me write the inequalities, then used algebra to finish. Noticing which terms to keep is made easier if you notice that in the worst case every puzzle is either tagged riddle or tagged both logical-deduction and mathematics, so the other terms shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

> Here's the edited Venn diagram: 
>  [image]

Comment: How are $k,a,b,x$ defined?

Comment: Added explanations to the answer.

Comment: Isn't this an incomplete proof ?  Don't  you also need to prove that x /(0.8k+a+b+2x) < 0.1  or equivalently, that (0.8k+a+b+x)/(0.8k+a+b+2x) > 0.9 ?

Comment: Edited my answer.